# getaddrinfo failing with error : Servname not supported for ai_socktype in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

This, I observed, because of the port. port is C++ string. When I hard code the port number say "4091" I dont see this issue. Any suggestions?

```
int sockfd;
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; 

cout << "port: " << port << endl;

const char * por = port.c_str();

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, por, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
}
```

Comment: I updated the questions. Its just addrinfo structure.

Comment: @Lamia Is this the actual code ? You are supposed to initialize `hints`

Comment: sorry I should have posted complete code. I updated it. Since I figured it port is the problem, I did not show that code before.

Comment: UDP-sockets are generally not used as passive sockets. Have you tried not setting `AI_PASSIVE`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, UDP sockets are used as passive sockets.  `AI_PASSIVE` just means "give me an address that I can bind to", as opposed to "give me an address I can connect to".  So UDP servers use `AI_PASSIVE` and UDP clients don't.

Comment: @JP: I just tried it. Still the same issue.

Comment: @Lamia: Don't get rid of `AI_PASSIVE`, `AI_PASSIVE` is absolutely necessary if `host` is `NULL` (such as this case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might look absolute dumb but this is how I fixed it.

```
    int pp = atoi(port.c_str());
    char buffer[50];
    sprintf( buffer, "%d", pp );   

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, buffer, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    }
```

EDIT: The actual issue was that I was reading the port information from a file. when I use the getline() it did not remove the newline char at the end for what ever reason. The above fix (if you call it a fix) no longer needed.

Comment: Let me be the first to say that that doesn't make sense. Have you tried calling `getaddrinfo` with `port.c_str()` directly? Maybe you should compare the different strings to see if they differ, it might be a sign of a bug in the compiler (while unlikely, it has been known to happen).

Comment: Yes I agree. I tried it 3 times, changing back and forth. It does not work with port.c_str().

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The actual issue was that I was reading the port information from a file. When I use the getline() it did not remove the newline char at the end for what ever reason. When I fixed it, it is working fine when I call getaddrinfo with port.c_str() directly. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to confirm that hardcoding the port has made this problem go away for me. I don't understand it, I'm actually consuming a third-party  python library (from Python) and so I had little idea of how to resolve the issue but I had an error message that matches this question, when I saw this answer I thought I had nothing to lost so I hard-coded the parameters and now the problem has gone away.